# Perl script to read and copy data to a hashtable and count occurrences

Tags: perl

```
while (<$SomeInputfile>) {
    $errors = "";
    if ($val_func->($_)) {
        print $SomeOutFile $_;
    } else {
        print $SomeErrorFile "Error on line $line_num: $errors\n$_\n";
```

whenever any error comes it prints in above format to someerrorfile.
Now what i want to achieve is to get type of errors with occurrences which means i need to get errors as a hashtable key along with counts and whenever any error is identified need to increase the count for the specific type of error but i m new to perl so unable to understand how do i achieve this. really appreciate help on this.

`$errors` contains data like list of type of errors as below:

```
Unknown CONTACT-RECORD-TYPE
Contact RECORD-LENGTH
Contact ACTION-CODE
Contact ACTION-CODE
.....
```

Comment: A frequency hash is easy, `++$freq{$errors}`, where `%freq` is declared ahead of that.  But this is missing pieces: do you classify (by frequency) mere values of the `$errors` variable like the expression above would (is that "_type of error_"?) or is there a more elaborate system?  Where should that happen -- what sets that `$errors`?  The code doesn't show.  I think it would help to clarify this (by editing the question, not in comments).

Comment: Thanks @zdim.. have updated the question with answers to your ques. please check and let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: "_updated the question_" -- thank you.  That still doesn't clarify: 1) where is `$errors` set? I guess this is not real code but still -- where should the frequency hash be built? Inside of `else` branch, item at a time as they come? Or by parsing the file with errors later? 2) Do you classify by `ACTION-CODE` (etc) or by the whole `Contact ACTION-CODE`? ///  I'd say that the answer by @vkk05 gives you enough but clarify above if you need more detail (and to leave a better question behind :)

Comment: To ans above yes it can be built inside else. and item at a time as they come. and its classified by whole contact ACTION-CODE .

Comment: "_classified by whole contact ACTION-CODE_" -- alright, then you can do `++$freq{$errors}` inside `else`. Declare the hash `my %freq;` outside the whole `while` so that it exists after `while` completes.  Then after the `while` loop, in that hash will be keys like `'Contant ACTION-CODE'` (and all other errors that came up), each with a value equal to how many times that error came up.

Comment: that helped me get the counts with list as well but i m getting like below when i m trying to print with the help of dumper. it keeps adding and final $var1 is the combined final list with correct details. just not sure how to extract the final $var1 from this. could you help on this please?
current format:-
$VAR1 = {
          'Contact RECORD-LENGTH' => 1
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'Unknown CONTACT-RECORD-TYPE' => 2,
          'Contact ACTION-CODE' => 1,
          'CONTACT-ID' => 1,
          'Contact RECORD-LENGTH' => 3
        };
like this there are 15-20 $var1 are there.

Comment: hm? If you declare `my %freq;` (name it better!) before the `while` loop, and in the `else` branch you add keys to it or increment counts on existing ones with `++$freq{$errors}` then after the `while` loop when you print it (with `say Dumper \%freq;`) there should be one `$VAR1` with all data.  It sounds like you make the hash every time through the loop...?

Comment: Do you print it as `print Dumper %freq` (the hash itself)?  Can't `Dumper` the hash itself, needs to be the _reference_ to the hash, so `print Dumper \%freq`.

Comment: have declared hash before while loop and incrementing counter inside while and when printing after while loop gives me multiple $var1.
my %freq;
while (<$SomeInputFile>) {
 $errors = "";
 if ($validator_func->($_)) {
  print $SomeOutFile $_;
 } else {
  print $SomeErrorFile "Error on line $line_num: $error_desc\n$_\n";
  ++$freq{$errors};
  
 $line_num++;
 
}
print Dumper \%freq;

Comment: What you show looks fine (presuming that all variables are set as needed etc), so I can't say but I expect it to be some silly little error.  Here is a suggestion: try to reduce your code to a short reproducible example -- a little program that can run and behave like you say.  I'd expect that you'll find some simple error in the process, but if you manage to make a short demo that still has the same problem then post that as another question.

Comment: This works. there was a small mistake and places the print statement correctly and it prints one $VAR1 now. but is there any way to format this output like if i want to remove the $VAR1 or array indices or may be adding something before each elements? is this possible ?

Comment: Printing with `Dumper` is just so we can see the data structure.  But normally you'll go through it and print things as you wish.  In this case, just iterate over keys and print values, like `for my $key (keys %freq) { say "$key => $freq{$key}" }` (use `printf` for alignment).  Etc...

Comment: used a while loop which worked.  while (my ($key, $val) = each %freq)
 Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions through out. Really appreciate. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a kind of hint answer:

You can alter this based on your requirement.

I am considering, you would be getting errors on each (`while`) loop and storing them in a hash by taking errors second string as a key.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %ERRORS;

foreach my $error ("Unknown CONTACT-RECORD-TYPE", "Contact RECORD-LENGTH", "Contact ACTION-CODE", "Contact ACTION-CODE"){
    my @whole_error = split / /, $error;
    $ERRORS{ $whole_error[1] }++;
}

print "ERRORS:\n".Dumper(\%ERRORS);
```

Result:

```
ERRORS:
$VAR1 = {
          'RECORD-LENGTH' => 1,
          'ACTION-CODE' => 2,
          'CONTACT-RECORD-TYPE' => 1
        };
```

Comment: Only issue here is errors are not limited to these 3 categories. it is around 30-40 categories.

Comment: Ok, like I mentioned you can alter the script based on as much as conditions you want. Maybe you can list the errors in your question.

Comment: what i wanted to covey here is we cant hard code all the errors like this as that may go increasing with time. is there any other way we can do this instead of hard coding all categories ? also once we enter into else block means we have received an error. so we need to increase the counter for the particular error category for which error is received.

Comment: If it(errors) always comes with two word string then the above script will work or you need to capture error with regex.

Comment: @Avengs "_we cant hard code all the errors_"  --- correct, you don't want that.  But this answer doesn't do that -- the hash is built by `++$ERRORS{$error_type}`, where `$error_type` is worked out above by splitting the string `$errors`.   No hard-coding of anything in that process.  (The explicit listing of errors in the loop condition is just for a demo so that this sample program can run.)  As for unknown types, you didn't specify what to do.  Some of these comments help, but should go into the question.

Comment: @Avengs This sorts errors (builds a frequency hash) by the second word in `$errors`.  So each different "type" will get its own entry in the hash.  If some of those are to be considered "unknown" (and not counted individually but lumped together) then you'd have to list somewhere which are considered "known".